# @ContentChild not working in directive applied to custom component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a custom component that is a `<h1>` tag and an `<input>` tag. I want be be able to access the input from my custom directive however when I try to use Angular's `@ContentChild` attribute, it is always `undefined`.
If I apply my custom directive to a native `<input>`, it works fine.

I have set up a StackBlitz highlighting this issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-contentchild-in-directive

If you open the JavaScript console after the page has loaded, you will see:

```
Native Component: ElementRef {nativeElement: input}
Custom Component: undefined
```

How can I access the `<input>` within the custom component from the directive?

Answer (score 1):

Well this behavior is because you are accessing `contentChild` with `Template Reference Variable` called `control`:

```
@ContentChild('control',null) public ctrlByName: any;
```

and it is only assigned to `input` element:

```
<input  #control name="Native Component" testDirective />
```

thats why `test-component` is not being detected by `ContentChild`

so you can actually assign `el` from `ElementRef` to your element and it will work fine, you wont need `ContentChild`:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.name = el.nativeElement.attributes.name.value;
    this.ctrlByName = el;
}
```

**[Working DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-contentchild-in-directive-pxyghp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest-dir.directive.ts)**

Comment: Now youve said `Template Reference Variable` i totally see why my code wouldnt work in this way.

Comment: I have also added a working example, please have a look